# Logging in to Laravel - additional form in front view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am a beginner in Laravel.
I have a question for the Laravel login system (uses 5.8).

I added standard login system to my project using:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

I now have pod domena.pl/register and domena.pl/register I have a login registration system.
This works fine for me.

I would like to add an additional login form on the main page (in domana.pl).

I made this form on the home page:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://domana.pl/login" id="registration_form">
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="RLRmSgFz3TrhXp7exjAzCDABf3OCErbf5DvxKCNI">
  <input type="email" name="email" required>
  <input type="password" name="password" required>
  <button type="submit" >Login</button>
</form>
```

However, after sending this form, there is no login and the page returns to the main page.
Does anyone know how to fix it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your blade view is similar to the code below so that this is the right CSRF token:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" id="login_form">
    @csrf
    <input type="email" name="email" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" required />
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Some reasons can explain your problem:

1. You got errors but you don't display them;
2. You're indeed logged, then redirected to the `$redirectTo` route (in `LoginController.php`) but nothing is displaying you're logged;
3. Laravel's throwing an error you don't see because you're running with `APP_DEBUG=false`.

You can display error using something like this:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" id="login_form">
    @csrf
    <input type="email" name="email" required>
    @if ($errors->has('email'))
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
    <input type="password" name="password" required />
    @if ($errors->has('password'))
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Add somewhere in your view data about the user. For example you can display the user's email if the user is logged in

```html
@auth
{{ Auth::user()->email }}
@endauth
```

Then check your .env file.